# Drupal table creation error

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-schema

I am trying to create a table in Drupal database using hook_schema function but I am getting the PDO exception error which I could not resolve. It would be great if you could provide me an solution to my issue

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 
You have an error     in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT '' COMMENT
'first name of the user', `lname` VARCHAR DEFAULT '' COMMENT' at line 3: 
CREATE TABLE {mage_user} ( `uid` INT unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 
'The foreign identifier for a mage user.', `fname` VARCHAR DEFAULT '' 
COMMENT 'first name of the user', `lname` VARCHAR DEFAULT '' COMMENT 
'last name of the user', `address1` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '' COMMENT 
'adress line 1', `address2` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'adress line 2',
`postcode` VARCHAR(7) DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'postcode', `gender` VARCHAR(6) 
DEFAULT ''  COMMENT 'gender' ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 
COMMENT 'The base table for mage user.'; Array ( ) in db_create_table() 
(line 2688 of E:\Server\drupal\includes\database\database.inc).
```

I am using

Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.3.10
MySQL client version: mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Revision: 321634 $

MySQL server version 5.5.21

and my schema definition is

```
    function mageacc_schema() {

          $schema['mageuser'] = array(
        'description' => 'The base table for mage user.', 
        'fields' => array(
        'uid' => array(
        'description' => 'The foreign identifier for a mage user.', 
        'type' => 'serial',  
        'not null' => TRUE,
  ), 
  'fname' => array(
    'description' => 'first name of the user', 
    'type' => 'varchar', 
    'lenght' => 255, 
    'default' => '',
  ),
      'lname' => array(
      'description' => 'last name of the user', 
      'type' => 'varchar', 
      'lenght' => 255, 
      'default' => '',
  ),
     'address1' => array(
     'description' => 'adress line 1', 
     'type' => 'varchar', 
     'length' => 255,
     'default' => '',

  ),
  'address2' => array(
      'description' => 'adress line 2', 
      'type' => 'varchar', 
      'length' => 255, 
      'default' => '',

     ),
     'postcode' => array(
      'description' => 'postcode', 
      'type' => 'varchar', 
      'length' => 7,  
       'default' => '',
    ),
    'gender'=>array(
    'description' => 'gender',
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'length' => 6,
    'default' => '',
    ),

  ), 

        );

  return $schema; 

}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: it would be helpful if you included the schema definition you are using

Comment: Hi Josep.. I haved added the schema definition and it would be helpful if you could tell me where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spotted a few typos with the 'length' property. Try fixing those first in **fname** and **lname** to see if it works.

Comment: You're welcome. It's a very common error with Drupal coding i'm afraid.